# Create isolated Interop.Word instance

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I need to create documents in background via Interop.Word. When I get new instance of _Application, it creates new WINWORD process with svchost.exe process as parent and sets Window visibility to Hidden.
But when I open Word document manually, it opens in a process created by App, but not in a new process. Also it makes hidden Word app with all opened documents in background earlier visible.

Is it possible to deny Word app created by me in code to use documents opened\created by user manually and create new WINWORD process with explorer.exe process as parent instead of using an existing one?

**UPD:**

Workaround:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188546

Comment: Why not use OpenXML to create the files, without the need for winword.exe and COM references?

Comment: To be honest, I've never about it. Thank you for the keyword. I used Interop.Word because it allows to form document, print it and convert to XPS to use it with DocumentViewer control.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround in the link above creates new WINWORD process for the documents opened manually:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188546