# Click on Start -> Microsoft word 2010 attaches a new blank document to existing instance

Tags: wpf, ms-office, word-automation

I am automating MSWord in a WPF application. Everything working fine, but 
a Click on Start -> Microsoft word 2010  attaches a new blank document to my instance which is already created by the Wpf application.How restrict this behaviour ?

```
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    Word.Application _oApp;
    Word.Document _oDoc;

    object oMissing =   System.Reflection.Missing.Value;  // Missing Value
    object oTrue = true;
    object oFalse = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Create_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            _oApp = new Word.Application();
            _oApp.Visible = true;
            _oApp.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = false;
            ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)_oApp).NewDocument += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(Application_NewDocument);
    }

    private void btn_AddDoc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _oDoc = _oApp.Documents.Add(oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
    }

    private void btn_RemoveDoc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _oDoc.Close(oFalse, oMissing, oMissing);

    }

    private void Application_NewDocument(Word.Document doc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("New: " + _oApp.ActiveDocument.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: @Irshad Please find the code in question ...

Comment: When I open Word app from start menu Application_NewDocument(Word.Document doc) event is not fired but the new blank document is added to _oApp.Documents

Comment: Could you be more specific about why the behavior is a problem? Would it be correct to assume you don't want the user "sharing" the instance of Word your solution is automating? In that case, your issue has been addressed in this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745668/create-isolated-interop-word-instance/20921151#20921151

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you very much for your help! The above thread fulfilled my requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. For administrative reasons, StackOverflow would appreciate it if you could perhaps create an "Answer" that includes the link to the KB article plus the code you've used to solve the issue. And then mark it as the "Answer". Then we can mark the older question as a "duplicate" and keep yours, which is more clearly stated. Would you have the time to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft listed this as a bug and illustrated a workaround to this problem in the following KB article

*BUG: Starting Word Manually Uses Same Instance as Automation* -
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188546

```
using System.Windows;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordAutomationTestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        Word.Application _oApp;
        Word.Document _oDoc;

        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;  // Missing Value
        object oTrue = true;
        object oFalse = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Create_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //To restrict the automation instance sharing with the user's documents. 
            //Create a temporary app instance and quit the same after the automation instance is created.
            //Ref :: Go through the following work around.
            //https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188546

            Word.Application temp = new Word.Application();      //Create temporary instance.
            _oApp = new Word.Application();                      //Create automation instance.
            temp.Quit(oFalse,oMissing,oMissing); //Close the temporary instance.
            temp = null;
            _oApp.Visible = true;
            _oApp.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = false;
            ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)_oApp).NewDocument += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(Application_NewDocument);
        }

        private void btn_AddDoc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _oDoc = _oApp.Documents.Add(oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
        }

        private void btn_RemoveDoc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _oDoc.Close(oFalse, oMissing, oMissing);

        }

        private void Application_NewDocument(Word.Document doc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New: " + _oApp.ActiveDocument.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

My sincere thanks to @Cindy Meister , for his help to solve this problem.